# Automation of C# Selenium Web Part

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, automation, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to handcode Automation of a SharePoint 2013 document library and am having trouble grabbing the ellipses control to open the webpart which contains the preview to the document.

Selenium is recognising the class name, which is the same value for all ellipses in the document library, however but not the XPath or CSS values.  I have used both Selenium IDE and FirePath to find the XPath values

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to write xpaths without tools, it is not so difficult. It is very flexible approach. 
Several tips:
1. Find element which contains text:

```
//*[contains(text(),'TEXT')]
```

2. Find element with text equals:

```
//*[text() = 'TEXT']
```

3. Element with attribute (id/class etc):

```
//div[@class = 'CLASS']
```

4. Div with class RIGHT which contains span with text:

```
//div[@class = 'RIGHT' and div//span[text() = 'TEXT']]
```

5. Find input with ID which contains text:

```
//input[contains(@id, "PART_OF_ID")]
```